Is there options to send Spark streaming executor metrics directly instead via driver?
I have Spark Streaming application lives on Argo + K8S that reads Kafka topics by subscribe pattern then there are some transformations and writing to a target.
Several different producers may write data to these topics and after the data is read, it is filtered by field and process data next only from 1 producer.
After filtering and transformations data will write to target DB and send Spark streaming metrics to Prometheus. I have a Grafana dashboard that monitor near real time custom metrics include latest read offset and oldest existing offset from Kafka but there is a problem. Because metrics will be sent only if application write something to DB (there was data from particular producer in topics so it passed through filter) i might have a situation that other producers overload topics but i won't see it.

Spark version: 3.3.2
Connection to Kafka spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12

Is it possible sending metric from executors immediately after getting it from Kafka or any other effective way to not lose these metrics?
